# Cannot share multiple images with sharekit

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I read the ShareKit documentation. It seems it can only share a single entity say image on a single button action. In my inference, All the methods incorporated deal with single entity at a time.

It generates the action sheet for a single item at a time.

I wished to share multiple entities of same "**type**" on a single button action using **sharekit** for same "**service**". Is it there a fix available for this?

Thanks in advance.